# TypeError: 'Workbook' object is not callable while using openpyxl module

Tags: python, openpyxl

i wanted to copy cell range and paste in another excel file for that i got a code but then it gave me the following error i tried resolving but could not encounter the error
THE ERROR

```
 line 5, in <module>
    s1 = wb('Table 1')
TypeError: 'Workbook' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\akki kisu\Desktop\pure ai>
```

THE MAIN CODE

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('schooldata.xlsx')
wb2 = load_workbook('new.xlsx')
s1 = wb('Table 1')
s2 = wb2('Sheet1')
for i in range(1, s1.max_row+1):
    for x in range(1,s1.max_column+1):
        s2.cell(row=i, column=x).value = s1.cell( row=i, column=x).value
wb.save('schooldata.xlsx')
wb2.save('new.xlsx')
```

Comment: You should use square bracket in line 5 and 6: `s1 = wb['Table 1']` because `wb` and `wb2` are not callable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the sheet by name use:

```
s1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Table 1')
s2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

---

Or as in the comments suggested use the `[]` brackets.

Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/working-with-excel-sheets-in-python-using-openpyxl-4f9fd32de87f) for working with excel in python.

Comment: this worked but how can i select specific cell range

Comment: `get_sheet_by_name` is deprecated.